# Changing of phrasal verbs by tenses

Tags: grammar, prepositions, american-english, phrasal-verbs, speech

Probably that is extremely strange question , but can I change pharasal verbs by tenses ?

*There is no something else information at the most popular resources .*

For example , **break down**

Past  Simple --- broke down

Present Simple  --- break down

Future Simple --- will break down

If true , what the forms ? (Simple Tenses , Future - in - Past , Passive Voice)

Comment: Could you make the question more to-the-point and clear? I can't understand what you're trying to ask. Also, why have you provided the sentence "There is no something else...resources" in the question? It doesn't seem like it is related, and is grammatically incorrect too.

Comment: I meant , "Is there an opportunity to change phrasal verbs at the times ? (future , past , present)"

Below , I stayed example 

And the second sentence meant , "There is no information about it in the Internet"

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: It seems clear. Basically can you inflect phrasal verbs for tense and/or aspect just as you would an ordinary verb, like "ran into", "would have run into", "was going to run into" etc. I'm tempted to simply say yes, though the damn gotchas in language always get me.  Something like "would have been running into" may be grammatical, but I'm not sure it sounds that great.

Comment: i.e if I want to tell somebody about future or past moments in my life I will have to use the same form ?

Comment: @ВикторСавченко Generally speaking you can. If you use the term "take out", which can mean "g. Slang. to kill or destroy.", and you're talking about "taking out" a most wanted terrorist, saying something like "I will have been taking him out for months", the phrase is undesirable for at least two reasons I can think of. It may be grammatical according to rules, but semantically either doesn't make sense or can be confusing. (also I'm combining the concepts of tense and aspect here). So generally, yes, you can, pretty safely. But it won't ALWAYS work as you intend it.

Comment: Thank you !!! You help me much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A phrasal verb such as *break down* (= *stop working, e.g. a computer*) can be used in the various past, present and future verb constructions because the action of *stop working* can take place in the past, present or future. It cannot be used in passive constructions because it is an intransitive verb and has no object.

But when *break down* means *hit something so that it breaks and falls to the ground*, then it can be passivized in the various constructions, because it is a transitive verb that requires an object:

- The door was broken down.
- The wall is being broken down.
- The hotel will be broken down.

However, just because a phrasal verb is grammatical in the various past, present and future verb constructions does not necessarily mean that it makes semantic sense. Take the verb "*to get at = to mean*"  for example. This makes sense in questions in the past and present tenses, continuous aspect:

- What are you getting at?
- What was he getting at?

But it difficult to conceive of a sensible context for the equivalent question in the future:

- What will you be getting at?

And it is even more difficult to come up with convincing sentences that contain *get at* in the simple aspect in declarative sentences.

In summary, most phrasal verbs, like most 'normal' verbs can in theory be used in the various past, present and future constructions. But, like many normal verbs, they do not always make semantic sense in those grammatical constructions.